# allowframebreaks with pausesections in tableofcontents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, pause, allowframebreaks

It sounds, using `allowframebreaks` in `\frame[allowframebreaks]` simultaneously with `pausesections` in `\tableofcontents` causes `pausesections` in `\tableofcontent[pausesections]` not to work. Here is a code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame[allowframebreaks, t]{\frametitle{Presentation Outline} \tableofcontents[pausesections]} 
\section{A}
\frame[t]{Section A}
\section{B}
\frame[t]{Section B}
\end{document}
```

[image]
I use "beamer" package and run it with "LuaLaTex".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: overlays and  framebreaks are two different concepts which don't mix well. Use either or, but not both. In fact, better keep away from framebreaks, there is a reason they are called evil in the beamer user guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the beamer user guide

> The use of [the `allowframebreaks`] option is evil.

Instead, I suggest to manually split the toc as required. This way you have full control over the breakpoint and you can make sure that it happens at a suitable place, e.g. at the end of a section and not within its subsections.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Presentation Outline} 
  \tableofcontents[pausesections,sections={-3}]
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}[t,noframenumbering]
  \frametitle{Presentation Outline} 
  \tableofcontents[pausesections,sections={4-}]
\end{frame} 
\section{1}
\frame[t]{Section A}
\section{2}
\frame[t]{Section B}\section{3}
\frame[t]{Section A}
\section{4}
\frame[t]{Section B}\section{5}
\frame[t]{Section A}
\section{6}
\frame[t]{Section B}
\end{document}
```